# How to calculate the time complexity of e sequential neural network in Tensorflow?

Tags: neural-network, gpu, big-o, tensorflow2.0, cpu

I have a sample neural network and am trying to see how much it would cost me to run it on a server and how long it would take to train if, for example, I add 3 more layers with around 4000,3000,2000 nodes in each layer respectively.

I understand that from a high level perspective the network needs to

1. Feed the inputs and get the results (which in turn will run Sigmoid) from the network which I guess happens in constant time (even tho the output may not be constant or even linear!)
2. Run Adam to optimize weights/biases which I guess also happens in linear time since it is like Gradient descent and is different in how it manages the learning rate!
3. Update the weights/biases which is constant!

I can't find a calculator to use and estimate the computation needed and I'm thinking of making one if I can get a good understanding of different variables in a neural network!

This is the code for my Tensorflow model:

```
const model = tf.sequential();
model.add(tf.layers.flatten({inputShape: [4317, 5]}));
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1000, activation: 'sigmoid'}));
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 4316, activation: 'sigmoid'}));
const optimizer = tf.train.adam();
model.compile({
    optimizer: optimizer,
    loss: 'meanSquaredError'
});
```

And here is the network summary printed by Tensorflow

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output shape              Param #   
=================================================================
flatten_Flatten1 (Flatten)   [null,21585]              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_Dense1 (Dense)         [null,1000]               21586000  
_________________________________________________________________
dense_Dense2 (Dense)         [null,4316]               4320316   
=================================================================
Total params: 25906316
Trainable params: 25906316
Non-trainable params: 0
```

What if I change the activation functions to linear or ReLU?

I have a laptop with **16 GB of memory and 3.2 GHz 8-core ARMv8-A** (M1 chip) and it looks like the laptop is taking about a minute to train a batch of 32 inputs.

Comment: For big-O, the CPU really doesn't matter. O(8 core) is O(1 core).

Answer (score 1):

With N inputs, each weight is used O(N) times per round of training, so assuming M weights you have roughly O(N*M) training time per round. It doesn't really matter where those weights are in your network. Even for recurrent layers (GRU,RNN, LSTM) this stays true.

Where things break down is that you can't let M go to infinity (which is how big-O works) because in that case your network training won't converge anymore. Effectively, it would be O(infinity).